# Автоматическое обновление данных таблицы средствами SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Как автоматически обновлять данные таблицы с определенной периодичностью средствами SQL?
Скажем, нужно создать таблицу, значения столбца в которой раз в полгода в определенный день месяца будут увеличиваться на 1.

Comment: [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)?

Comment: @Ainar-G дополнил вопрос. Имелось в виду средствами SQL

Answer (score 1):

Можно написать скрипт(например на языке PHP), который будет увеличивать значение на 1, 
после это запустить выполнение раз в полгода этого скрипта с помощью cron

вот тут подробно описано как им пользоваться:
https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/cron

Answer (score 0):

А зачем, если всё то же самое можно сделать через комбинацию статичных
данных и представлений?  Вот пример создания таблицы и представления,
в которых `amount` увеличивается на 1 каждые 30 дней:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (
  id     BIGINT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
, amount INTEGER
, date   TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
)
;
CREATE VIEW v AS
SELECT id
     , amount + FLOOR(
         EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW() - date) / EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM INTERVAL '30 days')
       ) AS amount
  FROM t
;
```

Ссылка на живой пример:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7jAdqJPNYRyh8RDc8guuCa/0.

Разумеется, всё это надо хорошенько покрыть тестами.